# Consuming web weather service in javascript

Tags: javascript, service, weather

I would like to use javascript to consume the web weather service provided by cdyne.
This is my code:

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>weather app</title>  
</head>  
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function CallService() {
        var DTO = "{ 'ZIP': '85281' }";

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (msg) {       
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(req + "# " + status + "@ " + error);
            },
            complete: function (req, status) {
                alert(req + "% " + status);
            }
        });
    }
    CallService();
    </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

When I ran the code, it shows the [object Object]#error@ and [object Object]%error in the alert, which means the error: function() and complete: function rather than success: function() are called. Is there anyone who used javascript to consume this weather service?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried the URL and it seems to be returning XML. Are you sure the URL is correct and that it should return JSON data?

Comment: [Here](http://konfabulator.wikia.com/wiki/CDYNE_weather_forecast) is a library someone wrote for using the cdyne wheather service in JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to use JSON, [here](http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/01/11/12-json-weather-apis/) is a list of weather API services, including some that support JSON.

Comment: @scott.korin: Yeah, I found that lib too, but it must be for desktop (non-browser) use (such as a Windows 8 widget), because the service clearly doesn't support CORS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems there:

1. Your URL should start with `http://`. Without it, the URL you have is resolved relative to the document the code is in.
2. You're sending JSON in the POST. The odds are very high that the service doesn't expect to receive a POST containing JSON.
3. You're expecting JSON *back* from the service, but it appears to reply with XML.
4. You're trying to do a cross-origin call, but that's prevented by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and the service you're trying to use doesn't appear to support [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). (When I tried it fixing the issues above, I got the error saying that the cross-domain request wasn't allowed from my origin [which was `http:/jsbin.com`]).

Looking at the [service description](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP) for the page you're trying to use, it doesn't look like it supports [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), either, which means you can't use it from a different domain. You'll have to use a server-side process to query it.

Comment: So should I use XML to do the query and also parse the returned XML?

Comment: @shaosh: As I said, I don't think you can do this (directly) from a browser at all, because of the SOP and the fact that the service you're trying to use doesn't seem to support CORS or JSON-P. So you'd need to do the query from a *server*, and of course since the result is XML, to use it you'd have to parse it. You'll probably have to make the query to your own server, which then gets the data from the other end, and sends it back. Or, of course, use an alternative service that supports CORS or JSON-P.

Comment: I got it. Really appreciate for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do ajax requests to a different domain, fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wAt45/

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP. Origin 
http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: This is the first time for me to use ajax. So I should not use ajax here?