# Error when consuming a web service with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to consume a web service ( http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl ) using JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function soap() {

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl',true);
var sr =
       '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
       '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">'+
     '<soapenv: Header/>'+
        '<soapenv: Body>'+
        '<web:ConversionRate>'+
     '<web:FromCurrency>EUR</web:FromCurrency>'+
     '<web:ToCurrency>TND</web:ToCurrency>'+
        '</web:ConversionRate>'+
        '</soapenv: Body>'+
        '</soapenv:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
            alert('onready');
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert('done use firebug to see response');

                }
            }
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 0) {
                alert('open() has not been called yet');
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 1) {
                alert('send() has not been called yet');
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 2) {
                alert('send() has been called, ...');
            }

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 3) {
                alert('Interactive - Downloading');
            }
            else
            alert('Consuming Error '+e.message);
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor/");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        xmlhttp.send(sr);
        alert("Hi WS");

        // send request
        // ...
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
            <input type="button" value="WS" onclick="soap();">
        </form>
</form>
```

In the execution I got the different messages mentioned in the `onreadystatechange()` function (even the error one!) but I couldn't know how to get the answer returned by the web service (I tried with this line `alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);` but in vain ), I don't know if I am doing it right and how to display the web service reply.

Comment: You won't be able to consume that web service like that due [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restrictions

Comment: I read from this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453910/xmlhttprequest-get-in-javascript-does-not-give-response?rq=1), that I should create a function called processRequest. In there you should check if xmlHttp.readyState is 4. If it isn't, just wait for the function to be called again.

This is stronge, because I got the alerts displayed many times (not one time) and finally I got the error.

Do you have any solutions for this problem? I want to consume this web service.

Thanks